# Is there a point to editing a question that should be moved to another SE site?

Tags: discussion, editing, migration

Sometimes I come across questions that really belong on another Stack Exchange site (usually Stack Overflow) that *also* have serious formatting, spelling and / or grammatical errors.

Is there a purpose in editing these questions on Super User while waiting for a moderator to come along and migrate it?

Answer (score 6):

The most important rule of migration is *don't migrate crap*.

So yes, feel free to edit them before you vote to or flag to migrate.

Comment: While I agree with this, I also [made a proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145204/allow-questions-to-be-nominated-for-migration-after-editing-in-the-review-queue) to allow for nominating migrations *after* editing, just because of the DMC policy. Feel free to vote for it too!